# Click to get Latitude and Longitude in google map using angular ng-map?

Tags: angularjs, ng-map, angularjs-google-maps

First of all I'm using Angular Google Map (ng-map). I want to get clicked location of google map's latitude and longitide.

My Code

```
<ng-map center="[{{latitude}}, {{longitude}}]">
   <marker position="[{{latitude}}, {{longitude}}]" title="how" animation="Animation.BOUNCE"></marker>
</ng-map>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do that this way, and also could get the coordinates even on marker drag:

```
<ng-map on-click="getpos($event)">
    <marker ng-repeat="p in positions" 
      position="{{p}}" on-dragend="getpos($event)">
    </marker>
</ng-map>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.getpos = function(event) {
    console.log(event.latLng);
};
```

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/413/)

**Update:** [with initialize](http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/427/)

**Edit** I would try

changing your js

```
app.run(function(editableOptions) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});
```

into

```
app.run(function(editableOptions, $rootScope) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    $rootScope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt,map) {
        $rootScope.map = map;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, mark it as an answer then. :P... it should... something else is not working... create a fiddle.

Comment: https://ngmap.github.io/#/!marker-animations.html => view this page. My project also like this.

Comment: In fact that is on dragevent... and you could use *$scope.getpos()* function... see the fiddle for the ng-map on-click.

Comment: Oh God..! In this map have the problem. In angular single page application this perfectly works for first time on page loading. After that its not works. only blank screen relies. How can i remove cache without page reload. Help me daniel.

Comment: I don't understand what is happening... can you show this in a fiddle?

Comment: http://rotary3230.in/15-16/business_dir/#/business_details/1 This is my page. Below in the location tab there is two locations (Valasaravakkam, test). After page load completion click any one's view map (It works perfectly). but the another one shows blank map. and also in the vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize in google maps:

```
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
alert("Latitude: " + e.latLng.lat(); + "\r\nLongitude: " + e.latLng.lng());
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to set one function on map click like

```
<ng-map center="[{{lat}}, {{lng}}]"  zoom-to-inculude-markers="auto" on-click="getCurrentLocation($event)">
        <marker position="{{latlng}}"></marker>
    </ng-map>
```

on your controller.js file you can set lat long like this

```
$scope.getCurrentLocation = function(event){

        console.log(event.latLng.lat());
        console.log(event.latLng.lng());
    }
```

Hope This will help you.